# sed -i with process substitution

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I want to search for Grades and replace them with some compliments as follows:

```
input_q1.csv:
roll,name,total,rank,grade
001,A B,78,23,C
003,F YZ,100,1,*
004,G H,12,112,F
```

output is as:

```
input_q1.csv:
roll,name,total,rank,grade
001,A B,78,23,Average
003,F YZ,100,1,Good
004,G H,12,112,Fail
```

and here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if cut -d"," -f5 input_q1.csv  | grep -q "\*\|A"; then
sed  -i 's/\*/Good/g;s/A/Good/g' <(cut -d"," -f5 input_q1.csv)
fi
if cut -d"," -f5 input_q1.csv  | grep -q "B\|C"; then
sed  -i 's/B/Average/g;s/C/Average/g' <(cut -d"," -f5 input_q1.csv)
fi
if cut -d"," -f5 input_q1.csv  | grep -q "D"; then
sed  -i 's/D/Poor/g;' <(cut -d"," -f5 input_q1.csv)
fi
if cut -d"," -f5 input_q1.csv  | grep -q "F"; then
sed  -i 's/F/Fail/g' <(cut -d"," -f5 input_q1.csv)
fi
```

I want to overwrite with the original file i.e, input_q1.csv but I know that process substitution creates a temporary file due which i am passing to sed command so it can't access the original file. Is there any alternative way to do it?

Comment: You can't edit a command substitution in place — the `-i` option has no place in the code you're showing.  Further, your `grep -q "\*\|A"` looks for the character sequence `*|A` which doesn't appear in your data.  If you want to look for a `*` or an `A`, it's probably easiest to use a character class: `grep -q '[*A]'`.  But fundamentally, that should all be done in a single `sed` script, with no process substitution and no `grep`.  Most alternatives are overkill (a Perl, Python or Awk script might be acceptable too, though `sed` can handle the job on its own).

Comment: Does it need to be one of sed or grep? Perl or awk is trivial.

Comment: I wanted to use sed with process substitution to search and  replace only in the 5th column, though i've already done it with single sed command.

Comment: Search is built into substitution; if there is no match on the "from" part, no substitution will take place. Thus, searching before attempting to substitute is pointless (except where you can somehow save a lot of processing time by not performing no-op substitutions).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually, in POSIX `grep`, `\|` is alternation, though I too would prefer `[*A]` for elegance, and agree with everything else you wrote.

Comment: @tripleee: I'd best go look at POSIX BREs again. They didn't always allow that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My bad, this seems to be a GNU `grep` extension, not a mandated POSIX behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file e.g. sed.dat:

```
s/,\*$/,Good/
s/,A$/,Good/
s/,B$/,Average/
s/,C$/,Average/
s/,D$/,Poor/
s/,F$/,Fail/
```

and use:

```
sed -f sed.dat input_q1.csv
```

Output:

```
roll,name,total,rank,grade
001,A B,78,23,Average
003,F YZ,100,1,Good
004,G H,12,112,Fail
```

If you want to edit your file input_q1.csv "in place" add sed's option `-i`.

Comment: The `sed` script hardly needs to be in a separate file.

Comment: thanks.. i forgot about "$"... although my doubt is still there if i want to search only in 2nd or 3rd column only

Comment: Then anchor accordingly; e.g. `s/^\([^,]*,[^,]*,\)[*A]/\1Good/` to substitute only in the third column. This works by requiring exactly two columns before the match, and capturing those two columns so you can replace them with themselves.

Comment: Thanxx dude!! got it!

Comment: just last question!!.. what is the use of \1Good/?? How can i use it in future??

Comment: `\1` is the text which was captured by the first set of parentheses. This is called a back reference. Wouldn't reading the manual make more sense than asking about fundamentals in comments already?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`.

Given:

```
$ cat /tmp/so.csv
roll,name,total,rank,grade
001,A B,78,23,C
003,F YZ,100,1,*
004,G H,12,112,F
```

You can use `awk` for the substitutions:

```
$ awk -F "," 'BEGIN {OFS=","; gr["C"]="Average"; gr["*"]="Good"; gr["F"]="Fail"} { if (NR>1) {print $1,$2,$3,$4,gr[$5]} else {print $0}}' /tmp/so.csv 
roll,name,total,rank,grade
001,A B,78,23,Average
003,F YZ,100,1,Good
004,G H,12,112,Fail
```

And then copy that to a temp file and then copy over the original:

```
$ awk -F "," 'BEGIN {OFS=","; gr["C"]="Average"; gr["*"]="Good"; gr["F"]="Fail"} { if (NR>1) {print $1,$2,$3,$4,gr[$5]} else {print $0}}' /tmp/so.csv > /tmp/tmp && mv /tmp/tmp /tmp/so.csv
$ cat /tmp/so.csv
roll,name,total,rank,grade
001,A B,78,23,Average
003,F YZ,100,1,Good
004,G H,12,112,Fail
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort!! but i want to use sed with process substitution only.

Comment: The code in the question covers grades B and D, though the sample data does not.

Comment: I wasn't trying to do a complete implementation -- just show the user how he might do it if he wanted to use `awk`  Easy to add...

Answer (score 0):

Though I think @dawg's solution is better and should be the accepted answer, the following is a pure Bash solution in case that you're interested:

```
grades_to_words () { 
    local IFS=,
    while read -ra arr; do

        len=${#arr[@]}
        grade=${arr[len-1]}

        case "$grade" in 

            C)  printf '%s,%s\n' "${arr[*]:0:len-1}" 'Average';;
            F)  printf '%s,%s\n' "${arr[*]:0:len-1}" 'Fail';;
            \*) printf '%s,%s\n' "${arr[*]:0:len-1}" 'Good';;

        esac
    done
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
$ # The first 'read' ignores the titles line.
$ { read; grades_to_words; } < input_q1.csv

001,A B,78,23,Average
003,F YZ,100,1,Good
004,G H,12,112,Fail
```